# Using list comprehension. with nested if

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-if

Given a list of filenames, we want to rename all the files with extension hpp to the extension h. To do this, we would like to generate a new list called newfilenames, consisting of the new filename. Using list comprehension#

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
newfilenames = [filename[:len(filename) - 3] + "h" for filename in filenames if filename.endswith("p")]
print(newfilenames)
```

output came `["stdio.h", "sample.h", "math.h"]`
Should be `["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need

```
filenames = [i[:-3]+"h" if i.split(".")[-1]=="hpp" else i for i in filenames]

print(filenames)
```

Comment: This fixes the problem with OP's approach, but it is not the simplest or best solution (since `str.replace` exists) and it should be explained in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply replace the `.hpp` with `.h`

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
x=[x.replace(".hpp",".h") for x in filenames]
print (x)
```

Output:

```
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']
```